Angular Material and css Flex layout
I have a component within an angular material card. The component has two divs, the content and the footer both of which are wrapped in a container div
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}
.footer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
}

The idea is the content fills the remaining space and is scrollable when the content exceeds the available space.
This looks great when the content is less than the size of its div, however as soon as exceeds the size of the div the footer is pushed down by a number of pixels.
I have done this in a simplified html page and all works as expected, as soon as I put the same html and corresponding css within an angular material card (in a dashboard) it behaves differently and looks horrible.
Has anyone come across this before and is there a solution or a work around?
Thanks in advance
Created on StackBlitz
https://angular-x1ww3x.stackblitz.io/

please share a stackblitz with the issue happens stackblitz

Why not take advantage of the mat-card-footer section in mat-card, which does precisely what you want to do with your footer css class. You can then simplify your component by removing the wrapper.
See: https://material.angular.io/components/card/overview


<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    Header (adds padding)
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    Content (adds padding)
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-footer>
    Footer
  </mat-card-footer>
</mat-card>




This doesn't really help in my situation as I am creating a generic data table component and the footer (pagination) is the data table component rather than the card

No worries. In that case have a look at the footer row of mat-table, see: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#footer-row. When adopting Angular Material, try to minimise any custom classes, it's not 'the way', and, when upgrading, the source of most issues.

I think the issue is with the card's styles and your flexbox configuration. you are almost there, to use Angular Material card's height,  I have provided you a code snippet to help you
For example:
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%; /*  the card would fill the container */
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%; /* wrapper for the full height of the card */
}

.content {
  flex: 1; /* remaining space of your content */
  overflow: auto; /* scrolling */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px; /* for footer*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


ensure the parent container height remains consistent use this

.parent-container {
  height: 100vh; /*  add other heights if you have them */
}


Finally place container in your html file...

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="parent-container">
  <mat-card class="card">
    <div class="your class">
      <div class="your content">
        <!-- Any element you want to scroll -->
      </div>
      <div class="your footer">
        <!-- where your footer lives-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-card>
</div>


Thanks for the suggestion but this is exactly as I have done and it works until the content begins to overflow. See my stackblitz for example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x1ww3x

OK - I solved the problem myself - flex-basis is the key here.
By adding flex-basis of 0 to the footer and flex-basis of 1 for the content.
